# Seamlessly create index with Searckick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, searchkick

For test purposes, I want to do something like this:

```
product = Product.create name: 'coffee'
product.reindex
```

This will fail, though, if the product index doesn't yet exist. What's the simplest way to create the index if it doesn't exist, or just use it if it does exist (and not reset it)?

Comment: maybe you'd consider this lazy,  but you could rescue the error.

Comment: Hoping for something cleaner, but it may be an option to rescue error, create the index with `import: false`, and just add this one item.

Comment: Just to be clear. There is a `Product` index that contains all of the `Product` records. You should call `Product.reindex` whenever you initialize this index for the first time. Then when a new `product` instance is added like in your above answer you can call `product.reindex` to add only that single, new product.

Comment: I'm curious on your use case: Why would the `Product Index` not yet exist? What sort of conditions do you have the dictate when to create the initial `Product Index`?

Comment: This is for unit tests, where the code in question doesn't know if the index has been created yet. It could call Product.reindex to be sure, but that has a performance impact